# Jquery & adding items to a shopping cart

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery and I have an exam tomorrow where i need to write a few lines of code. I need to create a var with products in it and images. I need to call the image and add it to the shopping cart. So far I have this:

Can feedback would be appreciated!!!

```
      $(document).ready(function() { // function contains everything, set to load when      page is ready

    var product;            // 3 global variables rest of function can use
    var source;
    var shoppingcart;

    var product = {                               //an array of products
    shoes: [
    {ladies: "High Heels", qty: 5},
    {mens: "runners", qty: 10},
    {childrens: "slippers", qty: 6},
    ]
     };

     var shoppingcart = ???????????

     var source = $("#myImage").attr("src"); //images are stored here

      $("#product").on("click", display_product);

      var validate_shoppingcart = (function() {
      shoppingcart.push($this)
    });

      OR SHOULD IT BE

  var validate_shoppingcart = (function (e){      // I am  Trying to call the image 
     $("#product").attr($this)
     });

      });
```

Comment: it's very hard to tell what's going on. some html would help. what's `validate_shoppingcart` called from?

Comment: Hi David,There isnt any html per se...the examiner is looking for the jquery code...I dont know if this helps

Comment: well for starters it doesn't make much sense to have an objects with such properties as `ladies`, those should be values, not keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
var products = {
    shoes: [
        {category: 'ladies', model: 'High Heels', qty: 10},
        {category: 'mens', model: 'Runners', qty: 5},
        {category: 'children', model: 'Slippers', qty: 6},
    ]
}
```

something like this would make more sense